# Cannot read property 'path' of undefined (Node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, path

I write app with react and node, but my localhost is not running and I have this error:

```
UNHANDLED REJECTION TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

All npm-modules are installed, but this error does not allow to launch my project. It is first time when I try to write code with node, so maybe answer is near.
My node.js below:

```
const _ = require("lodash")
const Promise = require("bluebird")
const path = require("path")
const select = require(`unist-util-select`)
const fs = require(`fs-extra`)

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, boundActionCreators }) => {
  const { upsertPage } = boundActionCreators

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const pages = []
    const blogPost = path.resolve("./src/templates/blog-post.js")
    resolve(
      graphql(
        `
      {
        allMarkdownRemark(limit: 1000) {
          edges {
            node {
              fields {
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
      ).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
          console.log(result.errors)
          reject(result.errors)
        }

        // Create blog posts pages.
        _.each(result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges, edge => {
          upsertPage({
            path: edge.node.fields.slug, // required
            component: blogPost,
            context: {
              slug: edge.node.fields.slug,
            },
          })
        })
      })
    )
  })
}

// Add custom slug for blog posts to both File and MarkdownRemark nodes.
exports.onNodeCreate = ({ node, boundActionCreators, getNode }) => {
  const { addFieldToNode } = boundActionCreators
  if (node.internal.type === `File`) {
    const parsedFilePath = path.parse(node.relativePath)
    const slug = `/${parsedFilePath.dir}/`
    addFieldToNode({ node, fieldName: `slug`, fieldValue: slug })
  } else if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const fileNode = getNode(node.parent)
    addFieldToNode({
      node,
      fieldName: `slug`,
      fieldValue: fileNode.fields.slug,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me which line the error occur?

Comment: It doesn't not show number of line exactly, but it shows this:

D:\IT\Valeria\Work\Project\client-only-paths\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:61
        `fn = function () { throw arg; };`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
   ).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      console.log(result.errors)
      reject(result.errors)
    }
```

you are not returning early in the if block, so the function is continuing and trying to do everything after.

Instead, just throw a return in there:

`return reject(result.errors) // Now will not continue`

But more specifically, there is no error handler on your promise, which is why you see the `UNHANDLED REJECTION` warning.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help, but I fixed it.
I delete npm modules, reboot my computer and install it again :)

Comment: Sorry :( Good luck